# Python socket connect to server with port forwarding

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip, portforwarding

I have open port 4545 on my router and forward it to the IP address of my desktop computer (for example `"101.102.103.104"`), and I want that machine in another network will connect to a socket server that I created in python on my desktop computer.

I wrote a client script on my laptop and connected it to a different network.
now, how can I connect to my python server?

**Python Server On Desktop Computer:**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostname(), 4545))

server.listen(5)

client, address = server.accept()

client.send(b"Hello from server")
```

**Python Client On Mt Laptop On Another Network:**

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(("101.102.103.104", 4545)) # "101.102.103.104" is the desktop computer public ipv4 IP address

print(client.recv(24).decode())
```

The server works fine, but how can I connect the client to my server?

Comment: You have to connect to the public address of the router, not the computer's address.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried to do that. How can I find my router IP?

Comment: ```ipconfig```  is not showing me the public IP of the router

Comment: You get it from the router itself. You can also use a web site like whatismyip.com

Comment: The website shows only my machine's IP. I can't find the router. Anyway, I'll try right now to find the IP from the router

Comment: My router IP is 10.0.0.101 (not really) it doesn't look like this is the public IP

Comment: That's it private IP. Get the IP of the WAN port.

Comment: Please wait..... I'm doing it right now

Comment: You should be forwarding to the private IP of the PC, not the public IP.

Comment: Hey, its me from my phone. I forward it to my private ip.

Comment: Do you have an idea to get the router ip?

Comment: @איתמרשיאון "*The website [whatismyip.com] shows only my machine's IP*" - the only way that is possible is if the machine is connected *directly* to the Internet and has its own public IP from your Internet modem. If the machine were connected to the router instead, then the website would only be able to show the router's public WAN IP.

Comment: On a side note, your server socket really should be using `server.bind(("", 4545))`, don't use `socket.gethostname()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a website like http://whatsmyrouterip.com/#routerPublicIP to find the public route of your router. Going to the website above will show you your routers public ip as well as its private ip along with some router information.

Comment: I got an error. I need to write ipv4 IP, not ipv6. How can I get the public ipv4 IP of my router?

Comment: @איתמרשיאון you really should be looking in your router's configuration for its IP.  But websites like the ones mentioned should be able to show it just fine, too. But, if your router does not have an IPv4 WAN IP, only an IPv6 WAN IP, then the client will have to connect to your router using IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) instead of IPv4 (`AF_INET`).

Comment: It's not working with ipv6. However, i think I'll have to call my internet service and ask them for my IP

Comment: Most users have a dynamic IP that changes over time, so asking the Internet provider what the current IP is may not be helpful. Also, if you involve the provider, they may decide to charge you extra for running a server on their system. You can trust that whatever public IP is reported by a site like whatismyip.com is accurate and what a client would need to connect to. If it is not working for you then you have not setup your environment correctly, most likely your port forwarding on the router